# Jacobian of $y = \Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\mu})$

Tags: statistics, jacobian

Jacobian of

$$y = \Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\mu})$$

I have done the following:

$y = \Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\mu})$ and $\mathbf{x} =\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{\mu}$.

Taking the first derivative for $\mathbf{x}$ with respect to y gives $d\mathbf{x} = \Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and the same for $\mathbf{y}$ gives $d\mathbf{y} = \Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Therefore,

$$|J| = \begin{pmatrix}0 & \Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}} \\\ \Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}} & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

This equals to $1$ but I should get that $|J| = |\Sigma|^{\frac{1}{2}}$ what am I missing?

Comment: If you need to get $\vert \Sigma \vert^\frac{1}{2}$ as your result then I guess you want the determinant of the jacobian of $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ with $f(y)=\Sigma ^\frac{1}{2} x +\mu$ as it is a linear transformation so the jacobian is $ \Sigma^\frac{1}{2}$ and it's determinant would be $\vert \Sigma \vert^\frac{1}{2}$, think of how $f(x)=ax+b$ then $f'(x)=a$. What you wrote doesn't make a lot of sense, I think you are mixing vectors $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with coordinates $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Aner That is super helpful! I was uncertain with performing a jacobian transformation because as its given in wiki we get a determinant matrix of derivatives. Although, what happens to the derivative of $y$?

Comment: @dolarbill You have $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $f=(f_1,\dots,f_n)\colon\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, there is not a single derivative of $y$, there is a matrix of all the $n\times n$ possible combinations of partial derivatives $\left (\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j}\right )$ which is called the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: @Aner Ok I see what you're saying; we only have function representations of the variable because they're mapping from one region to another, whereby an inverse mapping is allowed. I.e. your mapping notations. -- GOTCHA!!!! brilliant comment.